# Show the category custom fields in article page

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, joomla-api, custom-field

I have category custom fields and I need to show these in the article (which is in the category) view.

I have used the following:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\Component\Fields\Administrator\Helper\FieldsHelper;

// Get the category object
$customFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.category', $category, true);

var_dump($customFields);
```

This outputs as:

```
array(0) {
}
```

I need to output the custom fields. I have even tried the following

```
    <div class="custom_fields">
        <?php foreach ($customFields as $catfield) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<h3>' . htmlspecialchars($catfield->label) . '</h3>';
            echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($catfield->value) . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

but it's only outputting as:

```
<div class="custom_fields"></div>
```

Comment: This code is incomplete. How are you getting the category object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging that, I use :

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($customFields);
echo "</pre>";
?>
        <?php foreach ($customFields as $catfield) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<h3>' . htmlspecialchars($catfield) . '</h3>';
           
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

So, now you can see the content of the object with the properties you want. After that, you can user $catfield->YOURPROPERTIE